# PHP Calculation, break point, and reset value in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, reset

How do you calculate (sum) + a value in foreach loop?

I am working on a cricket application where i have to count the loop for each 6 times and then count specific value and then echo the total.

I have a code not exact but something like this.

And there are two values:

1. Balls $balls['1']; array like 1,2,3,4,5 and up to 300-1000 balls
2. Runs $balls['6']; array like 2,3,1,5 random numbers could be any;
3. Values comes from mysql table columns **balls** and **runs**

```
foreach( $balls as $ball ){
    $countball++;
    // here is what i need to know how do i calculate the values of $ball + $ball?
    // so i can echo it inside the below if condition?
    $runs = $ball['runs'] + $ball['runs']; // not working
    if($countball == 6){
        echo $runs;
    }
    $runs+= $ball; // reset the ball counting to continue addition from loop?
    // and reset the
}// end foreach
```

however something like this works fine for the first $countball == 6. but after that it does not show the exact value

Comment: For those of us who don't know cricket, could you show sample input data and the desired output?

Comment: `$runs = $ball + $ball` is the same a `$runs = 2 * $ball`. It's not a running total, you're resetting it each time through the loop.

Comment: pardon me i am new here, i edited the question to add more desc but the code format is now confusing.
yes i think i am reseting it so how do i reset the value for next loop  after if($coundball == 6) echo $runs and reset for next 6 loops?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, for correcting the question format

Answer (score 0):

You forget to reset the $countball.

You may change the if part as :

```
if($countball == 6)
{ 
    echo $runs;
    $countball = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yes but that's not the problem the problem is the $runs count!

Comment: Set `$runs = 0`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
$runs = 0;
foreach( $balls as $ball ){
    $runs += $ball['runs'];
}
echo $runs;
```

Comment: doesn't work, please tell me how do i simply sum a foreach value for example a value from current loop to be summed with a value with next loop?

Comment: You still haven't explained clearly what your desired result is.

Comment: i just want to SUM current $ball['runs'] with the next loop $ball['runs'];
Example result is : 
1. james 2 balls 3 runs
2. adam 1 ball 4 runs
3. james 1 ball 5 runs
end result what i need is total 12 runs from foreach loop only
 i can do it from another query to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @Barmar from above i got the desired output as followings

```
      $runs = 0;
        $countball=0;
        foreach( $balls as $ball ){
            $countball++;
            $runs += $ball['runs'];
            if($countball == 6){
//  reset runs from current loop runs for next, if i reset $runs = 0
//  for some reason it does not (SUM) + this loops $ball['runs'] with last 5;
            $runs = $ball['runs']; 
            $countball=0;
            }// end if $countball == 6
        }// end foreach
            echo $runs;
```